# Dynamic Right sizing for TCP

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, flow-control

I want to test the performance of tcp with and without [Dynamic right-sizing](http://public.lanl.gov/radiant/pubs.html#DRS).In [this link](http://public.lanl.gov/radiant/software/drs.html) patches for kernel 2.4.23 and 2.4.8 are present but nothing is mentioned about later versions of kernel. I would like to know if it is implemented by default in later versions or if any patches are avialable for the later versions of kernel.